# How to run three different process one by one

Tags: java, multithreading

Sorry for english this might be very basic Question, I have an Application where i want to perform three different operations

1. Taking Export From SVN
2. Creating Zip of the Folders
3. Uploading to Ftp

As these Operation takes some to for processes to complete.

How can i do this with Java, what is the best way to do this..

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [ANT](http://ant.apache.org) might be a good idea.

In particular:

- [ANT Zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)
- [ANT SVN support](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/svn/)
- [ANT FTP task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Java program which starts consequtevely the three processes. 
It can be done with the Java Runtime API, by which you can first start the SVN update/checkout/smth, then, if there are no errors, you can use the Java ZIP API to create a ZIP over the folder and finally, the Java Networking API to upload the resulting zip onto the FTP.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can [use ant programmatically](http://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html) from your application. Ant has tasks for your bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

1. SVN export, maybe use this library: http://svnkit.com/
2. Create ZIP, that is build-in in Java
3. Upload with FTP maybe with that one http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a *sequential* (not parallel) process, you only need one thread that does all three steps:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Take Export From SVN
        // Create Zip of the Folders
        // Upload to Ftp
    }}).start();
```

Even easier, you could simply write a normal java app with a `main()` method that does it all